# App Engine IP Range Change Notice

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, user-agent, urlfetch

Today I received the below Notice about "App Engine IP Range Change" :

> Google uses a wide range of IP addresses for its different services,
>   and the addresses may change without notification. Google App Engine
>   is a Platform as a Service offering which hosts a wide variety of 3rd
>   party applications. This email announces changes in the IP address
>   range and headers used by the Google App Engine URLFetch (outbound
>   HTTP) and outbound sockets APIs.
>
> While we recommend that App Engine IP ranges not be used to filter
>   inbound requests, we are aware that some services have created filters
>   that rely on specific addresses. Google App Engine will be changing
>   its IP range beginning this month. Please see these instructions to
>   determine App Engine’s IP range.
>
> Additionally, the HTTP User-Agent header string that historically
>   allowed identification of individual App Engine applications should no
>   longer be relied on to identify the application. With the introduction
>   of outbound sockets for App Engine, applications may now make HTTP
>   requests without using the URLFetch API, and those requests may set a
>   User-Agent of their own choosing.

However I'm not able to understand this notice very well and I would like to define the impact on my App Engine applications. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a separate non-GAE application that your GAE application connects to, where your non-GAE application allows connections only from known GAE IP's?

If so, you care that those IP's are changing.

If you don't have that setup, ignore!

Comment: My applications retrieve data from a Google domain that's all.
Do I have to care about this notice ?

Comment: No. I don't think so.